# How do I set the ManagedBy property on a GroupPrincipal

Tags: c#, active-directory, directoryservices

I'm creating and updating Groups in Active Directory using the `GroupPrincipal` class in `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`. When creating and updating, I also need to be able to set the `ManagedBy` property that you are able to set in the `Managed By` tab in the groups  properties in the AD management console.

Can it be done programatically?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot do this directly, unfortunately - but you can get access to the underlying `DirectoryEntry` and do it there:

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "YOURDOMAIN");

UserPrincipal toBeModified = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(".....");
UserPrincipal manager = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, "......");

DirectoryEntry de = toBeModified.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;

if (de != null)
{
    de.Properties["managedBy"].Value = manager.DistinguishedName;
    toBeModified.Save();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `tobeModified` be of type `GroupPrincipal` ?

Comment: @PBMe_HikeIt: no since that `managedBy` property isn't "surfaced" in the `GroupPrincipal`, you need to go "one level down" to the `DirectoryEntry` and deal with it there

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the GroupPrincipal class and provide a `ManagedBy` property using the [ExtensionSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.extensionset.aspx) method.

Comment: This is how I'm attacking the problem... though I'm having trouble making `ExtensionSet` work properly

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/118122/how-to-use-ad-attributes-not-represented-in-userpr) on Code Project looks like a great explanation as to how to extend the GroupPrincipal class using inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#13). This is one of the best tutorials on AD in c#.

Some code that should work(untested) :

```
    string connectionPrefix = "LDAP://" + ouPath;
    DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(connectionPrefix);
    DirectoryEntry newGroup = dirEntry.Children.Add
        ("CN=" + groupName, "group");
    group.Properties["sAmAccountName"].Value = groupName;
    newGroup.Properties["managedBy"].Value = managerDistinguishedName;
    newGroup.CommitChanges();
    dirEntry.Close();
    newGroup.Close();
```

Comment: That's not using the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace that the OP requested...

Comment: *http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/everythingInAD.aspx#13* not found